# change class only if all textfields are filled

Tags: jquery, html

i'm trying to change a class only when all the textfields are filled. but what i've realised is on each keypress the button changes class.

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $input = $('#city,#country'),
    $register = $('#go');

    $register.attr('disabled', true);
    $input.keyup(function() {
        var trigger = false;
        $input.each(function() {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                trigger = true;

            }
        });
        trigger ? $register.attr('disabled', true) : $register.removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.toggle').toggleClass('save2 save')
    });
```

HTML

```
<button class="toggle save" id="go">Save</button>
```

Comment: also, is there a reason you're using keyup instead of something like blur?  do you really want this to trigger with every typed character?

Answer (score 1):

The button class is changing with every keyup because you don't have this line wrapped in a conditional statement:

```
$('.toggle').toggleClass('save2 save'); //note:  you're missing the ; in your posted code.
```

If you only want the class to change when trigger is true, then wrap it in a condition:

```
if(trigger) {
   $register.attr('disabled', true);
   $('.toggle').toggleClass('save2 save');
} else {
   $register.removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

For example, given the following HTML

```
<input type="button" class="toggle" id="myBtn" value="My Button">
<input type="text" class="myText">
<input type="text" class="myText">
```

The following jQuery will change the class on every keyup:

```
$('.myText').on('keyup', function() {
  $('.toggle').toggleClass('save save2');
  console.log($('#myBtn').attr('class'));
});
```

But if you wrap the class toggle in a condition, it prevents the toggle unless the condition is true:

```
$('.myText').on('keyup', function() {
  var trigger = true;
  $('.myText').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      trigger = false;
      return false; //break the loop - there's no need to continue looping
    }
  });
  if (trigger) {
    $('.toggle').toggleClass('save save2');
  }
  console.log($('#myBtn').attr('class'));
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/63qkptu1/1/).

Comment: it works but when the user fills in the boxes and the class changes and clears out one textfiled the class doesn't reserve back

Comment: @user6579134 - Why not just check these inputs on a button click event?  When the user clicks a button to submit their entries, check that the inputs are filled in.  In addition to that, you can add "required" on the inputs.